# EntLib 5 Email Subject Line Edit?

Tags: smtp, enterprise-library

I am trying to change the subject line of email sent by Enterprise Library 5. I don't mean changing the subject line Starter/Ender (as seen in http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/69689?ProjectName=entlib), I want to change the actual Subject text, which is not the same as the Logger's Message Title.

All ideas appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source for `EmailMessage` in Enterprise Library 5 the subject is generated by

```
string sendToSmtpSubject = header + logEntry.Severity.ToString() + footer;
```

If you need to have complete control of the subject line in your email message you will need to extend the existing `EmailTraceListener` to include your added functionality.  (or simply modify the code and use your custom build of EntLib in your application).

Comment: How would this be extended? very interesting answer.